# How to setup a C++ project with MySQL Connector and Make

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, shared-libraries, mysql-connector

despite having developed applications in C++ for about two to three years, I never had to setup a project on my own. Most of the project were preconfigured thus I never learned to do it myself. Having lecture-free time at the moment, I thought to myself: "I am going to create my first own CMake C++ project".

Because I knew I wanted to store information in a database,I set off to create a simple CMake project with one executable linked to the MySQL Connector for C++, and instantly failed...

Since I - oddly - could not find helpful information anywhere else, I hope one of you could be my savior.

My project is setup as follows:

```
Root
- CMakeLists.txt
- build
- src
- tests
-- main.cpp
- include
-- mysql_connection.h
-- cppconn
--- driver.h
--- exception.h
--- resultset.h
--- statement.h
--- ...
-- ...
- libs
-- libmysqlcppconn.dylib -> libmysqlcppconn.7.8.0.12.dylib (symlink)
-- libmysqlcppconn.7.8.0.12.dylib
-- libmysqlcppconn8.1.8.0.12.dylib
-- libmysqlcppconn8.1.dylib  -> libmysqlcppconn8.1.8.0.12.dylib (symlink)
-- libmysqlcppconn8.dylib -> libmysqlcppconn8.1.8.0.12.dylib (symlink)
-- libssl.dylib
-- libcrypto.dylib
-- ...
```

My `main.cpp` contains:

```
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h> 
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","root","securepw");
    return 0;
}
```

And my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(EconSim)

add_executable(EconSim ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(EconSim PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(EconSim ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libmysqlcppconn.dylib)
target_compile_features(EconSim PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

I am able to compile the application but I get the following error when executing it:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/aosterthun/Documents/Programming/EconSim/build/./EconSim
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

When instead using `libmysqlcppconn8.dylib` in the `CMakeLists.txt`:
And my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(EconSim)

add_executable(EconSim ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(EconSim PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_link_libraries(EconSim ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libmysqlcppconn8.dylib)
target_compile_features(EconSim PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

I get a compile error:

```
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/aosterthun/Documents/Programming/EconSim/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 6
[build] [ 50%] Linking CXX executable EconSim
[build] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[build]   "_get_driver_instance", referenced from:
[build]       _main in main.cpp.o
[build] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
[build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[build] make[2]: *** [EconSim] Error 1
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/EconSim.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make: *** [all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

I found this: [How do I link C++ MySQL Connector Libraries to Cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165654/how-do-i-link-c-mysql-connector-libraries-to-cmake) but that sadly did not solve my problem.

I also found [CLion: undefined “_get_driver_instance”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513122/clion-undefined-get-driver-instance) which resulted in this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(EconSim)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_library(libmysqlcppconn STATIC IMPORTED)

add_executable(EconSim ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/main.cpp)
set_property(TARGET libmysqlcppconn PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/libmysqlcppconn-static.a)
target_compile_features(EconSim PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(EconSim libmysqlcppconn)
```

Which then results in this error:

```
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Users/aosterthun/Documents/Programming/EconSim/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 6
[build] [ 50%] Linking CXX executable EconSim
[build] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[build]   "_BIO_free", referenced from:
[build]       sha256_password_auth_client(MYSQL_PLUGIN_VIO*, MYSQL*) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(client_authentication.cc.o)
[build]       caching_sha2_password_auth_client(MYSQL_PLUGIN_VIO*, MYSQL*) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(client_authentication.cc.o)
[build]   "_BIO_new_bio_pair", referenced from:
[build]       dummy_function_needed_by_xplugin() in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(my_aes_openssl.cc.o)
[build]   "_BIO_new_mem_buf", referenced from:
[build]       sha256_password_auth_client(MYSQL_PLUGIN_VIO*, MYSQL*) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(client_authentication.cc.o)
[build]       caching_sha2_password_auth_client(MYSQL_PLUGIN_VIO*, MYSQL*) in libmysqlcppconn-static.a(client_authentication.cc.o)
[build]   "_BN_bin2bn", refer...
```

I would appreciate any help. Even a hint to an obvious solution I have not found. I am still a bit confused why I did not find helpful information on this topic. Cause there should be lots of people developing with this technology.

Just ask for further information if I missed any.

Comment: Depending on your needs, [Sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) might be easier to get off the ground.

Comment: That would be a sufficient solution. But I would still like to solve this problem due to personal interest ;)

Comment: Just a typo or are you referencing the wrong dylib? Should it be `libmysqlcppconn8.dylib` (note the `8`)?

Comment: I did try that and forgot to mention it in the post. Thanks for bringing that up. I added the problems I had with that approach in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

You need install openssl and link libraries libcrypto, libssl, libresolv.
I solve this problem as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
PUBLIC
    mysqlclient
    mysqlcppconn-static
    crypto
    ssl
    resolv
)
```

Comment: This saved my day, but it worked with "mysqlcppconn" , doesnt need to be static.